# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k$ converges absolutely for all $|x|<1/a$ if $a\ne0$ and for all $x\in\mathbb R$ if $a=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I am new to this site so I am not well versed on how things are done here. I would like some help with checking my attempt at this proof. What am I missing? Please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Proof: Let $a_k≥0$ and $a_k^{1/k}→a$ as $k→∞$. By the Root Test,

$\lim_{k→∞}⁡\text{Sup}|a_k |^{1/k}⇒\lim_{k→∞}\text{Sup}|a_k x^k |^{1/k}$

$\lim_{k→∞}⁡\text{Sup}|a_k x^k |^{1/k}$=

|x|$\lim_{k→∞}⁡\text{Sup}|a^{1/k}_k|=a|x|$

If $a≠0$ then it follows that the series converges absolutely when $a|x|<1$ or, $|x|<1/a$. For all $x∈\mathbb{R}$ if $a=0$, then the limit is zero, and by the Root Test the series converges absolutely.

Comment: If $a = 0$ there is no sequence so why not just concentrate on the first condition?

Comment: @mistermarko ?? One can have $|a_k|^{1/k}\to0$ and $a_k\ne0$ for every $k$.

Comment: Okay, is this sequence meant to bear some resemblance to the general form of a decimal expansion (with base x)? Anyone?

Comment: General form of a decimal expansion (for comparison with OP's serie): $Σ_{k=1} a_k \frac{1}{x}$ where $1 \le a_k \lt x$ and $a_k$ is an integer.

Comment: @mistermarko Surely you realize that the sentences you write mean nothing? Maybe this is a language problem, or a mathematical one, difficult to say.

Comment: @mistermarko Irrelevant comment (its only noticeable point, if any, is the age-old invocation of "insults" where there is none). Surely I should not add this but: how is $\sum_{k=1}a_k\frac1x$  supposed to be the expansion of a number? (But maybe this is an "insult" to ask this?)